# RXJS & Angularfire mapping not working

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I try to map 2 Firebase calls together. I am using AngularFire2 and RXJS.
I am getting a list with ID's and i want to get the object with that ID

```
const path = `/lists/${auth.$uid}`;
this.lijsten = map.call(af.database.list(path), (vals: any[]) => {
    return vals.map((m) => {
        m.shapes = af.database.object(`/lists/${m.$key}`);
        return m;
    });
});
```

This doesn't work for an extra firebase call. The call works, but it can't convert to JSON. If I replace it for a String, it works. 
I got this example from the youtube video from angular 
https://youtu.be/ngnSOTSS8Q8?t=1h11m48s

But when i use this example i can't convert it to json

```
lijsten | async | json
```

gives

> Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify ()

Is there a better way to map?

---

Update

I found when i use subscribe, it works

```
af.database.object(`/lists/${m.$key}`).subscribe(
      val => {    
        m.shapes = val;
      });
```

But still, is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `async` pipe twice, one for the `list` observable and another one for the `object` observable.

```
<div *ngFor="let list of lijsten | async">
  {{ list.shapes | async | json }}
</div>
```